# How to destructure an object that is stored as a state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, destructuring

Within a React App component, I am calling an API and storing the response within a local state. I then want to destructure the object that is stored in that state, but I can't just destructure right below the useEffect because it will throw an error before the call is completed.

Also, I don't want to break up the object within the useEffect, because I want the entire response for other things.

Here is an example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const [calledObj, setCalledObj] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    //Calling API here and setting object response as calledObj State
    setCalledObj(apiResponse)
  }, []);

  //This will throw an error when the API response has not been sent back yet.//
  // While this would be easy to write the whole path in the return, the actual path is really long.//
  const { name } = calledObj.person

  return (<div>{name}</div>)
}
```

Where can I destructure or how can I work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and/or the [nullish coelescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to work around it.

Note: IE doesn't support [either](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining) of [these](https://caniuse.com/?search=nullish), but babel will polyfill them.

```js
const { name } = calledObj?.person ?? {};
```

1. The optional chaining (the `?.` in `calledObj?.person`) prevents it from blowing up if `calledObj` is undefined.
2. The nullish coalescing operator (`??`) returns `{}` if `calledObj.person` isn't there.

With this combination the right side is guaranteed to evaluate to an object, so the destructuring on the left never blows up.

```js
let calledObject; // undefined;

// name is undefined, but it doesn't blow up.
const { name: name1 } = calledObject?.person ?? {};

console.log(`name 1: ${name1}`); // name 1: undefined

// ----------------

// now it's an object, but doesn't have a person property
calledObject = {};

// name is still undefined, still doesn't blow up.
const { name: name2 } = calledObject?.person ?? {};

console.log(`name 2: ${name2}`); // name 1: undefined

// ----------------

// with person.name present…
calledObject.person = { name: 'joe' };

const { name: name3 } = calledObject?.person ?? {};

// …it works as you'd expect
console.log(`name 3: ${name3}`); // name 3: 'joe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want your `name` variable to default to on first render, I guess you could do something like this:

```
  const { name } = calledObj.person ? calledObj.person : {name: ''}
```

Comment: This also works but can get a little long if you end up needed to grab a ton of items out of the object.

Comment: @ChrisScott I mean just change `{name: ''}` to `{}` and you will get the same exact result as your accepted answer. I only put it there so you have the option of setting `name` to some default value instead of `undefined` while your useEffect is loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your state with:

```
const [calledObj, setCalledObj] = useState({person: {}})
```

And this will put `undefined` in 'name' but is not breaking your code.